# Authentication Issue with REST call for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, django-rest-framework

I am currently trying to make a REST call from an iOS device. My code is below

```
 NSString *restCallString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyURL"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:restCallString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request addValue:Value1 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Header1"];
[request addValue:Value2 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Header2"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:restCallString]];

@try{
      _currentConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]   initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
@catch(NSError *e){
    NSLog(@"%@", e.description);
}
```

Whenever this is called, I get the following error: Authentication credentials were not provided. However, what confuses me is that if I send an identical GET request via a HTTP web console, it works perfectly. In other words, using the same URL and the same 2 header-value pairs, I get a valid response on a web console, and see no authentication errors. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the HTTP headers. This won't work, because the HTTP header is not contained in `$_GET` or `$_POST` because they're are not content, but description of the content expected.

Try this instead:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[restCallString stringByAppendingFormat:@"?Header1=%@&Header2=%@", Value1, Value2]];
```

Of cause you have to be aware that the URL is [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) compliant.

Comment: So I tried this, but I still get the same error. I am pretty sure the URL is valid given that the same URL works perfectly online. Is there anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: Okay. This was just a guess. Now I would need more informations about the API. I'm pretty sure you didn't read it's documentation properly, we need to know, how the API wants the authentication data to be passed.

Answer (score 1):

> if I send an identical GET request via a HTTP web console, it works perfectly

I suspect your web console is leveraging [`SessionAuthentication`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#sessionauthentication) — i.e. If you're already logged in to your site in your browser the API will authenticate you based on your session cookie.

Django Rest Framework provides various authentication methods and there are third-party options too. The simplest to get going is probably the provided [Token Auth](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#tokenauthentication) method.

Make sure this is enabled. Create a token in the admin (or via the provided view) and make sure you've set the `Authorization` header. It needs to look like this:

```
Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b
```

So your Objective-C will go something like:

```
  [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token %@", yourToken]
 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Hopefully that gets you started.